# custom notification with a RoundProgressBar

Tags: android

I want to put a circleProgressBar in myotification for displaying phoneMemory

1. I try to custom a RoundProgressBar extends View,but run error.I know notification just support some basic Controls after searching information online.
2. I try to Use System progressBar,but just horizontal progressBar can display progress rate,circle progressBar has been in rotation.

[image]

Comment: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification post from package com.fan.security: Couldn't expand RemoteView for:statusBarNotification...

Answer (score 0):

In reference to **[this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)** article, here are the steps you need to follow:

1. Create a `ProgressBar` widget in your **xml** file

   **Note**: ProgressBar is `circular by default`, if you want a horizontal one, set the style to `Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal`
2. Find the `ProgressBar` in the view using `findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_id)`
3. Use the `progressBar.setProgress(progressPercentage)` method on your `progressBar` to set the progress

Comment: hi,thank you for your answer，i‘ve tried to setProgress to a progressBar(circular),but it doesn't work,the bar just in rotation

Comment: do you mean that the rotation is in progress but not the specific percentage?

Comment: yes,What I need is a specific percentage, now i do it By using a imageView constantly replace progress picture